# Position of increment expression giving different array values

Tags: javascript

```
// Block 1

var ourArray = []; 

var i = 0; 

while(i < 5) {  
    ourArray.push(i);    
    i++;   
    console.log(ourArray); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]    
}



// Block 2

var myArray = []; 

var i = 0; 

while(i < 5) {   
    i++
    myArray.push(i); 
    console.log(myArray); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

Why does the position of my increment Expression `i++` affect the elements in the array?

Having the `i++` at the top in Block 2 seems to mean the array is no longer 0 indexed

Comment: Because `i` is incremented to 1 by the time you push it to array in block 2

Comment: Your array is still 0 indexed, you are just inserting different elements inside (in the Block 1 you're inserting values from 0 to 4 and in Block 2 you're inserting values from 1 to 5).
The `console.log()` just displays what is inside the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array was and still is Zero-indexed.

What changed are just the values that you pushed into it and not their indexes.

In the 1st case:
you push `i` first, then increment it by `1`, i.e., you start off by pushing `0`, then `1` and so on till `4`.

In the 2nd case:
you increment `i` first, then push it into the array, i.e., first increment `i` to `1`, and then push till `i` becomes `5`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ourArray = []; 

var i = 0; 

while(i < 5) {  
    console.log(ourArray.push(i)); 
    console.log(ourArray); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    i++;     
}
```

In the above example the value of i is getting printed first then it is incremented, thus it starts with 0 and ends at 4.

```
// Block 2

var myArray = []; 

var i = 0; 

while(i < 5) {   
    i++
    console.log(myArray.push(i)); 
    console.log(myArray); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

In this example the values of i is incremented first then it is getting printed hence it starts with 1 and ends at 5.

Answer (score 0):

The index of your array remains the same, only the stored values ​​that have been modified, this is because you are incrementing the variable i before storing in myArray. In Block 1 you store the value of i in the ourArray array and then increment.